# Jest: How to mock dynamic querySelector element and add eventListener on them

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, document, enzyme

In application user have ability to add a unlimited number of divs.
For every added div I use querySelector to attach event listener on that div.

How to mock in jest querySelector and adding event listener on element for which I use querySelector.

Example:

```
document.querySelector('#some-div-1').addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: what is behind `document`? do you use `jsdom`?

Comment: 1. I use React and I just attach event listener on my element like I show in example. When component is mounted.

jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => <div id="div-1">some div</div>);
and now I have error:
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addEventListener is not a function

2. I don't use jsdom

Comment: based on your tag "Jest" I'd expect we are talking about unit tests. They are not run in browser rather in isolated environment(nodejs). To work with browser-specific things like `document` or `addEventListener` [`jsdom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html) is typically used.